# Zend_Validate_Regex - allow only letters, numbers, and characters -_

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework

So, I have a text field that can contain only letters, numbers, hyphens, dots and underscores. I would like to validate it using Zend_Validate_Regex but this pattern does not work. Why?

```
/[a-z][A-Z][0-9]-_./
```

Here is my text element:

```
$titleSlug = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('title_slug', array(
    'label' => 'Title Slug',
    'required' => FALSE,
    'filters' => array(
        'StringTrim',
        'Null'
    ),
    'validators' => array(
        array('StringLength', FALSE, array(3, 255)),
        array('Regex', FALSE, array('pattern' => '/[a-z][A-Z][0-9]-_./'))
    )
));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your regex matches a string that *contains*  a lowercase letter, an uppercase letter, a digit, a dash, an underscore and any other character, in that order. You need this:

```
/^[\w.-]*$/
```

`^` and `$` anchor the match at the start and end of the string.

`\w` matches letters, digits and underscore; together with the dot and dash they form a character class (`[...]`) which is repeated zero or more times (`*`).

Comment: Just for my backup: In my case same thing was not working unless i did like this: `array('variable1' => '^[\w.-]*$')` remove the `/`

Comment: Tim's solution is working perfect. YumYumYum, I believe you need to use like this array('regex',true,array('/^[\w.-]*$/i')). I also amend Tim's regex by adding /i to ignore the case

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
 /[a-zA-Z]*|\d*|-*|\.*|_*/
```

Comment: A single character class is enough. Also, you need to anchor the regex.